# Python's list comprehension in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I do not know to properly call this, here is what I do in Python 2.7:

```
>>> "6C 7C 8C 9C TC".split()
['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC']

>>> cards = "6C 7C 8C 9C TC".split()

>>> [r for r, s in cards]
['6', '7', '8', '9', 'T']
```

If I use Ruby:

```
>"6C 7C 8C 9C TC".split
=> ["6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC"]

> cards = "6C 7C 8C 9C TC".split

> ????????????
```

My question lies in the `????????????` part. Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try it in irb?

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
2.1.0 :014 > s = "6C 7C 8C 9C TC"
 => "6C 7C 8C 9C TC" 
2.1.0 :015 > s.scan(/\w(?=\w+)/)
 => ["6", "7", "8", "9", "T"] 
2.1.0 :016 >
```

Note : *Regex* can be improved as per the need. But this is an idea, which can be used I think.

Comment: What if we need to turn `"T"` to `10`? Then we have to modify the regexp, so I prefer to use the block form of `collect` and `map`, when I need to do more things, I could change in the block. Thanks for showing the `scan` usage!

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect` or `map`:

```
cards.collect { |c| c[0] }
cards.collect(&:chop)

cards.map { |c| c[0] }
cards.map(&:chop)
```

Comment: You could use `cards.map(&:chop)` to get the first character, though.